# AWS EMR Error : All slaves in the job flow were terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I am using Elastic Mapreduce infrastructure on Amazon AWS. A jowflow got terminated automatically. Last state change reason according Amazon Console is : "All slaves in the job flow were terminated".

Create jobflow command :

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --name MyCluster --alive --instance-group master --instance-type m1.xlarge --instance-count 1 --bid-price 2.0 --instance-group core --instance-type m1.xlarge --instance-count 10 --bid-price 2.0 --hive-interactive  --enable-debugging
```

Details about jobflow : 
[image]

**Last few lines of log ...**

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201310231204_0099, Tracking URL = http://ip-10-197-16-105.us-west-1.compute.internal:9100/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201310231204_0099
Kill Command = /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.197.16.105:9001 -kill job_201310231204_0099
2013-10-23 14:11:38,618 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-10-23 14:11:48,741 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
```

As you can see above in logs, no error is thrown as such.

**What I think the reason is**

I think that this happened because of sudden increase in price od spot instances. More details in my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I am answering my own question.

I think that this happened because of sudden increase in price of spot instances. My bid price was $2 per instance per hour for a m1.xlarge instance.

**Snapshot of aws console spot instance pricing:**

[image: snapshot of aws console spot instance pricing]

You can notice the blue jumps in pricing. My bid was $2 and the actual price jumped to $11. Hence my cluster was killed automatically.

Comment: One of the strategy to avoid such problem would be to keep master and core instances as ondemand and task instances as spot. This will guard cluster against price jumps but lead to higher costs. This strategy is used  by AWS Datapipeline.