# EMR : All slaves in the job flow were terminated due to Spot

Tags: amazon-emr

We are having one issue with EMR and Spot instances.

We have clusters in different environment (different AWS accounts) in same region :

- One master node with market type : On Demand
- Two core nodes with market type : Spot

When the spot instances are terminated (over my maximum bids, out of capacity or wathever), the cluster terminate and I've only this message :
`All slaves in the job flow were terminated due to Spot`

After research, people already had this issues but it was due to a master node with market type Spot, this is not my case :

- [AWS EMR Presto Cluster Terminated abruptly Error: All slaves in the job flow were terminated due to Spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711372/aws-emr-presto-cluster-terminated-abruptly-error-all-slaves-in-the-job-flow-wer) (thought this one is curious because it presents an "on-demand" master node in the question but then explain its problem by the termination of the master node)
- [AWS EMR Error : All slaves in the job flow were terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550281/aws-emr-error-all-slaves-in-the-job-flow-were-terminated)

I tryied to find a response in AWS documentation but its all tell the opposite of what we suspect :the two core nodes termination, terminates the cluster

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has happened because you have chosen core node to be of `spot` type. If you read the best practices for instance type in AWS EMR, you will find that they suggest using **at least one on-demand instance for the core node**. Remember that this will come at **an extra cost**.

You can use instance fleet option for the core node and add both the spot and on-demand instance type to this instance fleet.

So the general thumb rule is

> Keep master and core instances as on-demand and task instances as
> spot.

I am adding a few links where you can read more about this and configure your cluster accordingly.

Link1: [Cluster configuration and Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-instances-guidelines.html#emr-dev-core-instance-group-spot)

Link2: [Types of nodes in EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Indeed I suspected that an EMR cluster requires at least one core node on demand to avoir termination. But the documentation is not very clear about that. On the mentioned Link1, I read that only a loss of a master node configured as a spot instance should imply a cluster termination.
Another thing not very well documented is that you can't describe a CloudFormation stack with EMR definition with only Task instances (even if you don't need HDFS usage).
Spot instances is quite something obscur !

Comment: At the end, I had the explain for my stuck spot renewal request : it tries to get a new instance until a certain timeout (TimeoutDurationMinutes 60 minutes by default) and if it fails, execute the provided TimeoutAction => TERMINATE_CLUSTER (the default) or SWITCH_TO_ONDEMAND.
Because my cluster has termination protection enabled, the cluster doesn't terminate but no further spot instance request will be made. It will remain stuck even if I resize the spot instances (thought forcing new requests)